# AWS notebook creation in EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS. I created a cluster in EMR. When I try to create a notebook, there is no any notebook in the console. I searched the documentation and it says in the panel there is a notebook to click. But I don't have it. How to create a notebook in EMR?

[image: AWS]

Answer (score 0):

Some regions don't support notebook. If you cannot find the notebook in the console panel so just change it to another region